# .Net based FAQ engine

Tags: .net

I have searched but could not find a FAQ "engine" built on .Net platform.

I found many in PHP, the most common of which is [phpMyFAQ](http://www.phpmyfaq.de/).

Are there any similar system in .Net ?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look in this control. It has implementation of FAQ logic:

https://www.syncfusion.com/faq/aspnet